# CMS for medium-sized enterprise websites

Tags: gratis, linux, cms, enterprise-portal

I'm searching for a "CMS" that would meet those requirements:

- free, possibly
- affordable (should handle 30.000-40.000 pageviews per day)
- should run on Linux
- should give the end-user (our internal users) the possibility to publish new images/new content (just static files, for now) without the help of the IT department
- should be scalable (should handle multiple web servers)

We don't need a complex CMS, our application logic is 95% in our java/jboss app.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think Alfresco, LifeRay, Drupal, Wordpress, and Fork-CMS all meet your criteria. You could spin up any of these on an instance and just hit them as an API from your java app.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721511/does-anybody-know-a-cms-with-api-functionality

Comment: Are Wordpress and Drupal (PHP-based, afaik) scalable on the web server tier? How?

Comment: All of them are scalable in a similar way. Here's a blog about scaling wordpress on AWS EC2 using autoscaling. http://www.mornin.org/blog/scalable-wordpress-amazon-web-services/  The basic idea is that you separate out the CMS components (database, application layer, load-balancer) through installation, then wire them together with configuration on the CMS. For each of these, just google for tutorials on auto-scaling <this CMS>.

Comment: I think some of these products offer paid-solutions where they do all of this for you, but that's a super spendy route to go if you're on a budget.

Answer (score 1):

I would point out [Instant Press 2.1](https://bitbucket.org/mulonemartin/instantpress/wiki/Home) based on the open-source web2py framework. Very easy to deploy to a miriad of web servers.

Comment: "very easy to deploy"... how? Just the web tier or the other tiers too?